# Any reference for implementation of 2-legged oauth with spring security?

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security

Any reference for implementation of 2-legged oauth with spring security ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked an open question, so there are some links I can point you to

http://getsatisfaction.com/oauth/topics/does_anyone_have_a_working_example_of_two_legged_oauth_using_java

http://bmocanu.ro/blog/2010/05/oauth-2legged-model-with-spring-security/

http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/

http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/twolegged.html